# How can we create a payment method in stripe?

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment, payment-method

I hope you guys are having a great time there. I have a question for you. How can we create a payment method by Stripe? I have a react component where I am loading the stripe elements. For loading the stripe element I need the payment intent from the server. And, to load the payment intent, we must send some amount of money because the `amount` field is required in stripe API. Do you guys have any idea how to implement this? How can we load the intent without sending the amount field? Or any other way to implement the payment method? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is called the deferred flow with SetupIntents. Please read through this [doc](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-deferred?platform=web&type=setup).

Comment: Thanks, bro. It should work. Let me work on that. Appreciate your response.